# Let $E$ be finite dim ext of a field $F$and let $G$ be a gp of $F$-automorphisms of $E$ s.t $[E:F]=|G|$ Show that $F$ is the fixed field of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

> Question: Let $E$ be finite dimensional extension of a field $F$and let $G$ be a group of $F$-automorphisms of $E$ such that $[E:F]=|G|$.  Show that $F$ is the fixed field of $G$.
> $\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$

My Thoughts: Let $K=\mathcal F(\Aut(E/F))$, thus we have $\Aut(E/K)\subseteq\Aut(E/F)$, but since $F\subseteq K$, we have $\Aut(E/F)\subseteq\Aut(E/K)$, so we get equality. So,
$$
|\Aut(E/F)|=[E:F]\geq[E:K]=|\Aut(E/K)|=|\Aut(E/F)|.
$$
Thus $[E:F]=[E:K]$ so $K=F$ and so $F=\mathcal F(\Aut(E/F))$, and since $E$ is finite dimensional and $[E:F]=|G|$, we have $F=\mathcal F(G)$.

But I am questioning my first sentence and my last sentence.  I am trying to do this without resorting to too much Galois Theory, but any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. If $F\subseteq K$ then $\mathrm{Aut}(E/K)\subseteq\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)$ (there is an inclusion reversion). Your stated inclusion dictates that every $F$-automorphism of $E$ fixes the larger field $K$ too which is not necessarily true.

Comment: Also, $G$ is *a* group of $F$-automorphisms of $E$ such that $|G|=[E:F]$. That means, in general, $G\subseteq\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)$ and not necessarily equality here (at least not yet). You seem to assume that $G=\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)$ in the begin.

Comment: @mrtaurho Ah, I see!  Could you help me see the reverse direction?  I've played around with it a bit, but I am having some trouble.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about the behaviour of $\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)$ in a non-Galois extension. Anyway, if I'm not mistaken $G\subseteq\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)$ gives $F\subseteq\mathcal F(\mathrm{Aut}(E/F))\subseteq\mathcal F(G)$ and, moreover, we have $[E:\mathcal F(G)]=|G|=[E:F]$ implying the result (this also should entail that $E/F$ is actually Galois to begin with!).

Comment: That is starting to make some sense!  My one question: how can we be sure that $[E:\mathcal{F} (G)]=|G|$?

Comment: That's the part I'm not sure about either (and that's the reason I only commented rather than answered)!

Comment: I see.  I do appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I have found a reference for the only needed fact: [Proving the number of K-automorphisms is bounded by the degree of the extension by considering field embeddings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835782/proving-the-number-of-k-automorphisms-is-bounded-by-the-degree-of-the-extension).

The linked question asks for a proof for the bounding $|\mathrm{Aut}(L/K)|$ from above by $[L:K]$. It is a rather elementary argument as it turns out. Anyway, I will freely use this fact now.

Back to your question. Consider $E/F$ finite and $G\subseteq\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)$ with $|G|=[E:F]$. We then have
$$
|G|\le|\mathrm{Aut}(E/\mathcal F(G))|\le[E:\mathcal F(G)]
$$
by definition of $\mathcal F(G)$ and using the fact from above. But, $[E:\mathcal F(G)]\le[E:F]$ and $|G|=[E:F]$ implying that $[E:\mathcal F(G)]=[E:F]$ which is only possible for $\mathcal F(G)=F$.

---

By the way: In this case we have also have $|\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)|=[E:F]$, by the given inclusions and bounds, implying at once that $E/F$ is actually a Galois extension (and $G$ its Galois group).

Comment: Awesome!  That answers it!  Thank you so much for your help - I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @User7238 Glad to help! Make sure to double check the Math.SE thread I linked. :)

Comment: @User7238 As it turns out we actually do have $[E:\mathcal F(G)]=|G|$ in general. If you can read German, take a look at the [following](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unabh%C3%A4ngigkeitssatz_von_Dedekind#Verwandte_Resultate); if not, the linked article states exactly the desired conclusion and links it to a theorem of Dedekind on the linear independence of certain characters (Dedekind's lemma as the other Math.SE calls it).

Comment: Very cool!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the standard result that if $G$ is a finite subgroup of group of automorphisms of any field $E$ then the the fixed field $E_G$ of $G$ has the property that $[E:E_G] =|G|$. The proof of this result involves showing that $[E:E_G]$ is finite and does not exceed $|G|$. Once we know that the extension $E/E_G$ is finite we can apply a little bit of Galois theory to get $[E:E_G] =|G|$.

We are given that $F\subseteq E_G$ and thus we get $F\subseteq E_G\subseteq E$. Now you can use the tower law to get $$[E_G:F] =\frac{[E:F]} {[E:E_G]} =\frac{|G|} {|G|} =1$$ and thus $E_G=F$.